# Zeroing memory on Windows

Tags: performance, c, memory-management, windows, winapi

I need some useful functions that faster than the original. (Original - C++'s functions)

For example:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

struct TestMemory {
    double a,b,c;
};

void* __TestMemory__Sample=0;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE h1,HINSTANCE h2,LPSTR str,int i) {
    AllocConsole();
    __TestMemory__Sample=calloc(1,sizeof(TestMemory));
    TestMemory* test=(TestMemory*)malloc(sizeof(TestMemory));
    clock_t c1=clock(),c2;
    for (int i=0;i<100000000;i++)
       memcpy(test,__TestMemory__Sample,sizeof(TestMemory));
    c1=clock()-c1;
    c2=clock();
    for (int i=0;i<100000000;i++)
       memset(test,0,sizeof(TestMemory));
    c2=clock()-c2;
    printf("memcpy: %d\nmemset: %d\nradio: %f (set/cpy)",c1,c2,c2/(float)c1);
    getchar();
}
```

Output:

> ```
> memcpy: 1410
> memset: 3250
> radio: 2.304965 (set/cpy)
> ```

This function replace the current way to zero memory.

What it does:

1. Create a global pointer, first set with zeroed memory.
2. When you want to allocate zeroed memory, allocate memory with `malloc` and then copy the zeroed memory (global variable) to this memory.

Comment: 1) Did you turn on the optimizer. 2) Did you check to see if your code has been removed by the optimizer. 3) Check that you are timing what you think you are timming.

Comment: I know about all of those ,but I need more then this. I am programming scripting language. I need to make it fast as native (C++).

Comment: As expected I get the exact opposite: `memcpy: 141861
memset: 139421
radio: 0.982800`

Comment: That's when you enabling optimizations ,it's deleting all the code. Use it in variables that you really use.

Comment: Sorry ,but I need this.

Comment: Need _what_? You have an idea, which may or may not be faster than just using memset under some circumstances. Is that what you need? Or you need it to actually be faster?

Answer (score 1):

Beware of optimising things, trying to get tiny improvements. By running your program with varying optimisation settings, I got the following ratios (memcpy/memset):

- 1.8
- 1.0
- 0.8
- 5.1

I think you can use these to prove anything you like. If your program is running too slowly, your attention probably should be directed elsewhere.

Comment: That's when you enabling optimizations ,it's deleting all the code. Use it in variables that you really use.